# Tensorflow: why passing dense matrix is noticeably faster than sparse?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use tensorflow 0.14 to train a recommendation system using collaborative filtering algorithm.

If I have

```
ratings = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])
ratings_dense = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(ratings, validate_indices=False)
```

and later use `ratings_dense` in all calculations, it is significantly (10x) slower than having

```
ratings_dense = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])
```

and passing prefilled numpy array.

Why is that so?

Comment: My guess is that if I pass `ratings` as a sparse tensor, `ratings_dense` gets recomputed with every training step.

Comment: same issue.. using sparse matrices reduce my model size by orders of magnitude, but the computation of the gradients becomes really slow.